# Prevent hash navigation url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following problem:
I'm using a slider (coda) to let people navigate trough some 'pages'. The slider uses hash links to navigate to the next page/slide. If a user is at page one (#page1), there is a link which will lead the user to page 2 (#page2) and so on. At the top of the slider the numbers of the pages appear as a link, but only when the page is visited. So if there are six pages and the user navigates from the first to the second and then the third one, there are only three links at the top of the slider (to page one, two and three).

The problem is that a user can navigate to page five (or any page actually) without first visiting the pages previous to page five by just using the hash URL and typing the whole link in their address bar. For example if I would type

www.mydomain.com/slider/index.php#page5

the slider automatically navigates to the fifth slide/page of the slider and thereby skipping the first four. I want to allow users to navigate to #page5 only if they have visited the first four (So by clicking trough the slides). This means that if they would go to #page5 directly by typing the URL in the address bar, I would like them to be send to the first page (#page1).

Does anyone have any idea on solving this?

Comment: The point of these hashes it to give the user the freedom to share links to specific slides. Why would you want to take that away from them?

Comment: And if you don't want them to have that ability … why would you write the code to use it in the first place?

Comment: This question isn't answerable in its current state anyway, we can't tell you which bits of code to delete without being provided with the code.

Comment: @Quentin That's not really true; OP mentioned that he was using a slider plugin called "coda". A quick Google reveals that the Coda slider does not have built-in hash management; instead it creates anchor tags, then subscribes to events on those tags and reads href attributes. This is answerable.

Comment: Hmm, I spoke too soon. Coda source doesn't explain this. Looking at the [Coda source](https://raw.github.com/KevinBatdorf/codaslider/gh-pages/js/jquery.coda-slider-3.0.js), it doesn't appear to watch the location.hash variable like you're describing...can you post your code with JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

If this is really a problem for you, you could simply remove any hashtag on document ready and reload the page.